# How to override view and display a message (Linux)

Tags: linux, terminal, centos

I'm currently running a CentOS environment which provides HTTP service. It is connected to a LAN and only local users can access it.

If, for any reason, the local DNS fails in any way, the users may still access the server using the local IP address directly (192.168.1.N instead of, say, myservice.lcl). However, my users have no access to the physical server or the router so they cannot see or find out its IP.

The server is always hooked to a monitor, which is always on (waiting for login). I want to display on it the ip address of the server, without granting anybody access; namely, I want a black screen with white big font displaying ONLY the IP address without having any user logged in. This way, my users may know what address to type on their browsers with a quick glance at the screen.

Is there any way to do this?

EDIT: The IP Address is not static, it may vary from time to time, so I would need to get this via "ifconfig"

Comment: Use as background an image with the IP written as big as you want :-) If the server does not have a graphic login system, modify the login message adding the IP in  `/etc/issue`.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem since the IP could very well be dynamic.

Comment: Add information about the login. It is textual or graphical?  If graphical it is a real login screen or a session screen lock? And which kind of graphical environment? Write it and maybe you will find an answer to your specific case... else it is too wide.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a graphic login manager probably you can set up a custom background image, so it is enough to create it with your IP written as nice as you want.

If the server does not have any graphic login you can add in the "welcome message" the IP, modifying e.g. the file `/etc/issue`.

It can be useful [this post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-change-login-message/).

If you lock the screen (graphic session) you can use a screen-saver with a custom background image...

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem since the IP could very well be dynamic.

Comment: Since 192.... is a private network with DNS I suppose you can set the IP of your server to the last one available for your network and you will be almost sure to have no conflicts...You check in your router and exclude it from the dhcp set...